# Composer doesn't connect to github in my docker image

Tags: php, docker, composer

TEngo algunos problemas para instalar mi imagen de laravel con docker Cuando trato de instalar las dependencias con composer. Coloque un diagnose par ver que sucedia y tuve como respuesta lo siguiente:

```
=> ERROR [stage-0 10/23] RUN composer diagnose                                                                                                                                                      16.1s
------
 > [stage-0 10/23] RUN composer diagnose:
#0 0.227 Composer plugins have been disabled for safety in this non-interactive session. Set COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 if you want to allow plugins to run as root/super user.
#0 0.227 Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
#0 0.232 Checking platform settings: OK
#0 0.232 Checking git settings: OK git version 2.30.2
#0 0.244 Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
#0 0.480 Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
#0 0.734 Checking github.com rate limit: A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.
#0 15.76 FAIL
#0 15.76 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: Resolving timed out after 10003 milliseconds
#0 15.76 Checking disk free space: OK
#0 15.76 Checking pubkeys: FAIL
#0 15.76 Missing pubkey for tags verification
#0 15.76 Missing pubkey for dev verification
#0 15.76 Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
#0 15.76 Checking composer version: OK
#0 16.09 Composer version: 2.5.8
#0 16.10 PHP version: 7.3.33
#0 16.10 PHP binary path: /usr/local/bin/php
#0 16.10 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
#0 16.10 cURL version: 7.74.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1k
#0 16.10 zip: extension not loaded, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
```

no se conecta a github si alguien tiene alguna idea de que puea estar pasando se los agradecere

gracias

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).